# Do I need to delete the pointer returned by std::localtime?

Tags: c++

This is currently how I am getting system time:

```
void Sum_AnalogClock::GetSystemTime()
{
    std::time_t t = std::time(0);   // get time now
    std::tm* now = std::localtime(&t);
    angleSeconds =  now->tm_sec;
    angleMinutes = now->tm_min;
    angleHours = now->tm_hour;
    if (angleHours > 12)
        angleHours -= 12;
}
```

Do I need to `delete now;`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, according to [1] it points to an internal data structure, so you don't need to delete it.

[1] https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/localtime

Comment: He should call `localtime_r` so his code is thread safe.  However, I believe all modern implementations of `localtime` are also thread safe, just not documented as such.

Answer (score 3):

No, according to the STD - std::localtime returns a "pointer to a static internal std::tm object on success".

So no need to delete anything.

Lior